# Error while launching android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Have see many other questions similar to it and tried all those still no use to me, so please help me
The error is

> The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin) does
>   not point to a valid JVM insatllation.

I tried setting these as path for `JAVA_HOME`

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51;
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51
```

but no use, i had jdk 7 and it showed same error so i installed jdk 8 and removed 7 and set the paths accordingly but no use, yes my package version is 51 i checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAVA_HOME shouldn't be set like a path - it's a single directory. Just use 
    **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51**